# How to Call the /oauth2/token endpoint with our app’s client_secret to exchange the code for an access token for DropBox in Swift?

Tags: swift, oauth-2.0, token, dropbox

I am using SwiftyDropbox to integrate Dropbox with my iOS App. I have completed all the configurations and implemented the code as in the documentation. User need to access the files in their dropbox account through my app. When I tried with 'generated access token' (got from dropbox console), I was able to access the files in my own account only. I understood that we will need to use the standard OAuth flow to obtain access tokens for other users.

[image]

Followed the steps as explained in https://developers.dropbox.com/oauth-guide

1. Constructed a Dropbox authorization URL, with my application’s client_id and redirect_uri.
2. Next step is to Call the /oauth2/token endpoint with my app’s client_secret to exchange the code for an access token. I am not sure how to implement this. If any of you have solved this before, please advise. Some portions of my code is given below.

   override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   ```
        self.actionDropboxLogin()
    }

    func actionDropboxLogin() {
        if (DropboxClientsManager.authorizedClient != nil) {

            //User is already authorized
            //Fetch images from user's DropBox folder
            self.getImageFromDropbox(path: "", isBack: false)
        } else {

            //User not authorized
            //So we go for authorizing user first.

            guard let rwURL = URL(string: "https://www.dropbox.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=myclientid&redirect_uri=https://myapp/callback&response_type=code") else { return }


            let scopeRequest = ScopeRequest(scopeType: .user, scopes: ["account_info.read files.content.read files.content.write files.metadata.read file_requests.read"], includeGrantedScopes: false)
              DropboxClientsManager.authorizeFromControllerV2(
                  UIApplication.shared,
                  controller: self,
                  loadingStatusDelegate: nil,
                  openURL: { (url: URL) -> Void in UIApplication.shared.openURL(rwURL) },
                  scopeRequest: scopeRequest
              )
            self.getImageFromDropbox(path: "", isBack: false)

        }
    }`

    func getImageFromDropbox(path:String, isBack:Bool) {
        let client = DropboxClientsManager.authorizedClient
        if client != nil {
       //code for getting list of folder, images or videos here.
   ```

   }
   self.tableView.reloadData()
   }

When I print the value of client in console it is nil. So the condition 'if client != nil' is false and I am not able to get the files. Which means I am not getting an access token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the SwiftyDropbox SDK, you don't need to handle any of the /oauth2/authorize or /oauth2/token details directly. The SDK implements the app authorization flow for you. You should only implement the flow as documented here:

https://github.com/dropbox/SwiftyDropbox#configure-your-project

Comment: Thanks for confirming this. I tried it again with iPhone and its working. I can get the client access token now. But it was not working in my iPad.